# Building cordova apps fails on linking step

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When i try to Archive my project for release I get the following issue:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Eazybreak/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/bogdan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Eazybreak-ctqyotqyclrvjoghewxpdeoemnkd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Eazybreak/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libCordova.a (2 slices)
```

I checked my build settings but I cannot figure out why it occurs.
Thanks in advance and any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you will need to update the Build Settings in your project

1. Select your Project icon
2. Choose Build Settings.
3. For “Architectures”, select $ARCHS_STANDARD – Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)
4. For “Valid Architectures”, add “arm64″
5. Select your CordovaLib.xcodeproj icon
6. In the Build Settings for the Project (not Target), delete *all* the conditional architecture settings (hover to see the minus sign). This is what is recommended by Apple in their Xcode 5.1 Release Notes.
   7 . For “Architectures”, select $ARCHS_STANDARD – Standard architectures (armv7, armv7s, arm64)

8 .**For “Valid Architectures”, add “arm64″**

9
 . Goto 6, but now do it for “Target“

More details http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/

Comment: arm64 is present in my Valid architectures along with armv7 and armv7s. trying now, hopefully it works.